# How to model a solr index to rank student technical skills?

Tags: solr

I am trying to figure out how to design my SOLR index schema to index students skills and levels (beginner, intermediate, expert) and be able to search for multiple skills (without indicating level) and have SOLR return the students ranked accordingly (based on the level).

> Example :
>
> John Doe has the following skills:
>
> - ruby : expert
> - javascript : beginner
>
> Mark Smith has the following skills:
>
> - ruby : beginner
> - javascript : intermediate
>
> Susan Denver has the following skills:
>
> - ruby : intermediate
> - javascript : intermediate

Searching for "ruby" should return

- John
- Susan
- Mark

Searching for "javascript" should return

- Mark - Susan (same score)
- John

Searching for a combination of skills even gets trickier.

The solutions I have in mind include using tags like structured like [skill]_[level] and have one field of the index contain the tags. Then convert the query keyword into all the various tags ...

Other option, is to create on dynamic field per "skill" : skill_ruby, skill_javascript and have the level as value.

But I am sure there must be a more straightforward solution has this is certainly been modelled in other scenarios (product ratings etc ..)

What is the correct index schema to index this type of data ?

Comment: Any reason why your `skill_ruby`, `skill_javascript`, etc. strategy wouldn't work? Dynamic field names matching the specific skill types should be straight forward to implement and can be used as boosts or in a function query to weigh them differently as needed.

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution I came up with, but I just wanted to make sure I was modelling my index the right way. We also have a nested skill taxonomy. For example, if you have 5 years experience in Spring Boot, you should also match for 5 years experience in Java .. But than expansion can be triggered at query time of course. I was only worried about the potential explosion of dynamic fields .. but maybe that is a non issue.

Comment: Usually it is not - and by using docValues you also remove most issues with memory usage if you're sorting by a large number of distinct field names. Do as much expansion as possible when indexing - the more you can calculate up front instead of while querying, the better.